# what is the meaning of this angle parameter in vlfeat's sift function?

Tags: sift, vlfeat

[image]

I am wondering what the output parameter angles is and why the length of angle is 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [original paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf), section 5. Orientation assignment:

> An orientation histogram is formed from the gradient orientations of sample points within a region around the keypoint [...] Peaks in the orientation histogram correspond to dominant directions of local gradients. The highest peak in the histogram is detected, and then any other local peak that is within 80% of the highest peak is used to also create a keypoint with that orientation. Therefore, for locations with **multiple peaks of similar magnitude**, there will be **multiple keypoints created at
>   the same location and scale but different orientations**.

This is also explained by the VLFeat implementation (see [sift.c](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/f363f3abf9e55cb117fdbdcdfe44b95ec838ca5f/vl/sift.c#L410-L413)):

> This histogram is then smoothed and the maximum is selected.  In
>   addition to the biggest mode, **up to other three modes** whose amplitude
>   is within the 80% of the biggest mode are retained and returned as
>   **additional orientations**.